# Build Error: GOPATH set to GOROOT (C:\Users\Admin\go) has no effect, cannot find main module

Tags: json, go, warnings, root, gopath

```
package main
import "fmt"

    func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

Its my first code, but ended up with this error, I tried many times to resolve issues like this in VSCode.

> Build Error:
>
> warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (C:\Users\Admin\go) has no effect go: cannot find main module, but found .git/config in d:\GO\practise  to create a module there, run:  go mod init (exit status 1)

Comment: Stop fiddling with GOPATH and GOROOT. Follow https://go.dev/doc/ . Use modules.